# How to debug custom ASP.NET MVC Text Templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, t4

How do you go about debugging the T4 process when you are customizing the template?

I've followed the procedure in [Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) to add the templates to my project so that is uses them when using the Tooling Dialog but how to I debug that template when it uses it?  The documentation [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures1T4TemplateDebuggingInVisualStudio2012.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126247.aspx) is not really helpful since I've cleared out the Custom Tool property.

For example, I'm trying to customize the List.tt and I'd like to loop through the properties of the Model inside the Index method.  I'd like to have a look at what's hanging off the Model object, etc.

My current process is edit the List.tt, right-click on controllers folder, add Controllers, enter the name, select my model, choose 'Overwrite xxxController.cs' and then check to see if what I did worked. This is extremely tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the custom tool property back in to be able to rapidly test it? then take it out when you are happy?

another option is to write a .tt file that consumes/includes that .tt to operate as your [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) harness